# Calculate line integral type 1 $\int_C z\,ds$

Tags: integration

With $C:x^2+y^2=z^2,y^2=ax$ form point $O(0,0,0)$ to point $A(a,a,a\sqrt2)$.
Calculate line integral type 1:
$$I=\int_C z\,ds$$

I have some problems with this exercise. I have idea that let $x=x(\phi),y=y(\phi),z=z(\phi)\rightarrow I= \int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} z(\phi) \sqrt{x(\phi)'+y(\phi)'+z\phi'} \, d\phi$:

First, we have $y^2=ax$, hence $x^2+ax=z^2\rightarrow (x+\frac a 2)^2-z^2=\frac{a^2}{4}$

Hence let $x+\frac{a}{2}=\frac{a}{2} \cosh(\phi),z=\sinh(\phi)$

At point $O(0,0,0) \rightarrow \phi =0$ but the problem is at point $A(a,a,a\sqrt2),\phi $ is a irrational number ( I can't calculate exactly )

Can everyone help me? Thank u for your help

Comment: In your case $z = \frac a2\sinh \phi$, otherwise the parametrization seems to be correct. What's the problem with $\phi$ being an irrational number at $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having difficulty with the way you have parametrized, you can parametrize the curve as,

$r(x) = (x, \sqrt{ax}, \sqrt {x^2+ax}), \ 0 \leq x \leq a$

Once you find $|r'(x)|$, multiply by $z = \sqrt{x^2+ax}$ and you can get the integrand down to the form $\sqrt{u^2-b^2}$. Finally use $u = b \cosh (v)$ substitution and you are done.

Based on how you are parametrizing,

$r(t) = \left(- \dfrac{a}{2} + \dfrac{a}{2} \cosh (t), a \sinh \left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right), \dfrac{a}{2} \sinh (t) \right)$,
$0 \leq t \leq \cosh^{-1}(3)$

$r'(t) = \dfrac{a}{2} \left(\sinh (t), \cosh \left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right), \cosh(t)\right)$

So integral is,

$\displaystyle \frac{a}{2} \int_0^{\cosh^{-1}(3)}  \sinh(t) \ |r'(t)| \ dt$

Can you take it from here? After simplification,  a substitution of the form $a +  \cosh (t) = b \cosh (u)$ may be required.